# Xcode app keyboard looks stretched

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an iOS app, built in Xcode using Objective-C, released and on the app store.

I have noticed that the keyboard in my app seems to be quite a bit taller than the default keyboard of other apps on my phone, for example the built in apple mail app.

[image]

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Is there any reason for the size difference, and is there any way to change my code or app set up to get the "proper" default keyboard in my app?

My code for the text input fields in my app is as follows...

```
    usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    usernameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    usernameField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    usernameField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16];
    usernameField.placeholder = @"username";
    usernameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    usernameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    usernameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    usernameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    usernameField.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
    usernameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    usernameField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    usernameField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    usernameField.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollview addSubview:usernameField];

    passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    passwordField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    passwordField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16];
    passwordField.placeholder = @"password";
    passwordField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    passwordField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    passwordField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    passwordField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    passwordField.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
    passwordField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    passwordField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    passwordField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    passwordField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
    passwordField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    passwordField.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollview addSubview:passwordField];
```

Comment: This is most propably due to the fact that you haven't made your app "compatible" with iPhone 6/6s/7 and 6+/6s+/7+. Without it, iOS will render your app, including keyboard and status bar, in iPhone 5 resolution and scale it up to fit bigger screen. All you have to do is provide launchscreens for bigger iPhones and everything should work.

Comment: @Losiowaty You were first to respond, but added a comment rather than an answer, so I can't credit you for the response!

Comment: I'm not doing this for credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correct size launch images to fix this problem. The application will be scaled according to the launch image and will give you the proper resolution.

Launch images should be used in below sizes.

1. iPhone 4s - 640*960
2. iPhone 5,5s - 640*1136
3. iPhone 6,7 - 750*1334
4. iPhone 6+,7+ - 1242*2208

Thanks

Comment: This looks to have fixed it. Thanks!